# How do I timeout an event in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to detect if the `mousedown` event is held for a period of time before a `mouseup`.

I'm using timeout() on an Observable created with `fromEvent()` to do so, but the timeout returns both Observables.

Below, subscribing to stream returns the event if `mousedown` is triggered within 1 second, but it also returns 1.

```js
var mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(target, 'mousedown');
var stream = mousedown.timeout(1000, Rx.Observable.return(1));

var sub = stream.subscribe(
    function (x) { 
        console.log('Next: '+x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Err: '+err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Complete');
    }
);
```

However, this works as expected:

```js
var source = Rx.Observable.return(42)
    .delay(200)
    .timeout(1000, Rx.Observable.return(1));
```

I'd like this code to work:

```js
var mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(target, 'mousedown');
var mouseup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(target, 'mouseup');

var clickhold = mousedown
.flatMap(function (){
    return mouseup.timeout(1000, Rx.Observable.return('hold'));
})
.filter(function (x) {
    return x === 'hold';
});

clickhold.subscribe(
    function (x) { 
        console.log('Next: '+x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Err: '+err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Complete');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using [`timeout`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/timeout.md), I used [`delay`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/delay.md) and [`takeUntil`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/takeuntil.md):

```js
var target,
    mousedown,
    mouseup;

target = document.querySelector('input');

mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(target, 'mousedown');
mouseup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(target, 'mouseup');

var clickhold = mousedown
    .flatMap(function(){
        // Triggered instantly after mousedown event.
        return Rx.Observable
            .return('hold')
            .delay(1000)
            // Discards the return value if by the time .delay() is complete
            // mouseup event has been already completed.
            .takeUntil(mouseup);
    });

clickhold.subscribe(
        function (x) { 
            console.log('Next: ' + x);
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log('Err: ' + err);
        },
        function () {
           console.log('Complete');
        }
    );
```

```html
<script src='https://rawgit.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/v.2.5.3/dist/rx.all.js'></script>

<input type='button' value='Button' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You came up with a great solution on your own. Here's what I would change:

1. Move the inner observable (`timer(...).takeUntil(...).select(...)`) out of [`flatMap`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md), so it isn't re-allocated for each mouse down.

You've got the rest right. For my usage, I usually retain the original `mousedown` event and use that instead of `'hold'`. That requires `returnValue` and `delay` instead of `timer` and `select`.

```js
var target,
    mousedown,
    mouseup;

target = document.querySelector('input');

mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(target, 'mousedown');
mouseup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(target, 'mouseup');

var clickhold = mousedown
    .flatMap(function (e) {
        return Rx.Observable
            .return(e)
            .delay(1000)
            .takeUntil(mouseup);
    });

clickhold.subscribe(function (x) { 
        console.log('onNext: ', x);
    });
```

```html
<script src='https://rawgit.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/v.2.5.3/dist/rx.all.js'></script>

<input type='button' value='Button' />
```

Or, for a completely different approach...

```
var Observable  = Rx.Observable,
    fromEvent   = Observable.fromEvent.bind(Observable, target),
    holdDelay   = Observable.empty().delay(1000);

Observable
  .merge(
    [
      fromEvent('mouseup')
        .map(empty),
      fromEvent('mousedown')
        .map(Observable.returnValue)
        .map(holdDelay.concat.bind(holdDelay))
    ]
  )
  .switchLatest();
```

Ok so that's weird. I'm really just giving it as food for though, and to show off that this can be done in a number of different ways.

Comment: Thanks!  I was thinking about using switchLatest as well, and your example makes it clear how I can use it.

Comment: As a follow up how would you check for the mouseup after the 'clickhold'?  I'm subscribing on Observable.when(clickhold.and(mouseup).then(function(){ return 'release';}), mouseup.then(function(){ return 'mouseup';}), to reverse state.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're asking. Phrasing such as "check for" works out really well when talking about syncronous pull-based systems, but I have a hard time understanding it when we're talking about events. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Basically I want to check if the 'clickhold' sequence is followed by a mouseup.  For example if I click on a box and change its color, then on mouseup I'd like to change the color back.  I have a solution here that uses when(): http://codepen.io/geekrelief/pen/FAimL?editors=101 But I wonder if there's a less verbose way of doing it.

Comment: You might be interested in Paul Taylor's unified gestures library for RxJS. https://github.com/trxcllnt/rxjs-gestures

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely look into it!