# Angular 2 RxJS check if mouse event is still active after delay

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using Angular 2 to make a directive. I have the following events bound to the host component:

```
host: {
    '(mouseenter)': 'onMouseEnter($event)',
    '(mouseleave)': 'onMouseLeave($event)'
}
```

I also created two streams and listeners on the directive to manage the two events

```
export class PopupDirective {
    private _mouseEnterStream: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    private _mouseLeaveStream: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    onMouseEnter($event) {
         this._mouseEnterStream.emit($event);
    }

    onMouseLeave($event) {
         this._mouseLeaveStream.emit($event);
    }
}
```

I want my `subscribe` to only be called if the `mouseenter` event is still active after a fixed delay (i.e., a `mouseleave` hasn't occured). I tried doing it this way, but it doesn't work (which makes sense, I just don't know how to fix it).

```
this._mouseEnterStream.flatMap((e) => {
  return Observable
    .of(e)
    .takeUntil(this._mouseLeaveStream);
}).delay(2000).subscribe(
  () => console.log('yay, it worked!')
);
```

Does anyone with Angular 2 / RxJS experience know how I should approach this?

Comment: Where does `this._mouseStream` come from?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry that should be mouseEnterStream

Comment: btw, since you're using Rx, you really don't need EventEmitters. Just use Subjects instead. Kind of surprised you can use EventEmitters as Observables, maybe ng2 converts them under the hood.

Comment: @kakigoori Isn't the whole point that EventEmitters *are* Observables? Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: typically to use EventEmitters for Observables in other projects, you have to use the static `fromEvent` method to generate an observable from an event emitter. i used to be a heavy user of event emitters, but cold/hot streams, operators, and the whole creation/subscription/disposal is just too nice. (you might find Andre's post here useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338930/reactive-programming-rxjs-vs-eventemitter-in-node-js/35239241#35239241)

Comment: @kakigoori That was helpful thank you. It looks like ng2's EventEmitter might be a misnomer then. [Looking at the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/EventEmitter-class.html) it seems very intentional that EventEmitter is based on Observer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Günter's answer is exactly what you expect but you should use the `of` operator instead of the `return` one that doesn't exist.

```
this._mouseEnterStream.flatMap((e) => {
  console.log('_mouseEnterStream.flatMap');
  return Observable
      .of(e)
      .delay(2000)
      .takeUntil(this._mouseLeaveStream);
}).subscribe(
  (e) => {
    console.log('yay, it worked!');
    console.log(e);
  }
);
```

See the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/vP3xRDXxFanqzLEKd3eo?p=preview.

Also, there is [a proposal in Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13248) that aims to simplify the way observables are created from DOM events using Rx via template syntax.

Comment: If it's just a single value you want to return, `.just` makes more sense. But to non-Haskelly-lang users, it might be gibberish.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this operator doesn't exist with Rxjs 5.0.0-beta.0. See this error: `Rx_1.Observable.just is not a function`

Comment: Oh, sorry, looks like it is listed in the migration docs for RxJS5 beta. Kind of sad though.

Comment: Not sure why `.subscribe` needed to be connected to `.flatMap` for this to work, but this is perfect! Thank you.

Comment: It's just to create the data stream. When the first event is received, it will be mapped to another chain that handles the delay...

Answer (score 3):

Looks quite similar to [How do I timeout an event in RxJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985416/how-do-i-timeout-an-event-in-rxjs)

```ts
this.myStream = this._mouseEnterStream
    .flatMap((e) => {
        return Observable
            .of(e)
            .delay(2000)
            .takeUntil(mouseLeaveStream);
    });

myStream.subscribe((x) => { 
        console.log('onNext: ', x);
});
```

I don't use TS or Rx myself (only Dart) therefore I don't know if this is the correct syntax or if the name of the operators match with these available for Angular.

Comment: Interestingly I tried this option exactly before making this post - but for some reason .susbcribe needs to be connected to .flatMap in order to make it work - otherwise "next" fires immediately on a mouseenter event.