# Issue with Observable/Subject delay/throttle (ngIf & async)

Tags: angular, rxjs5, ngrx

I'm working with `@ngrx/store` and I'm displaying notification when request starts or returns an error and hiding it if request is successful. It works as intended, and I wanted to delay initial notification so it's not shown if request ends quickly. I've tried several Observable/Subject operators that work with time:

- With `delay` and `bufferTime` **message** is `null` which causes an error in  `<notification>`
- Using `debounceTime` doesn't show initial message, but with slow responses and errors **message** is still `null`
- `throttleTime` only shows initial notification and hides it with slow responses

Without any of these `*ngIf="(notification |async)"` does it's job and **message** is set only if notification isn't `null`.

I suppose I could just hide `<notification>` with CSS transition delay, but I was wondering if anyone knows other way to solve this...

```
@Component({
  template: `<notification [message]="notification |async" *ngIf="(notification |async)"></notification>`
})
export class RootRoute {
  constructor(...) {
    this.notification = this.store.select('notification')
      // None of these solve my issue:
      // .delay(250)
      // .throttleTime(250)
      // .debounceTime(250)
      // .bufferTime(250)
  }
}

export class Service {

  private request(method: any, values: any, endpointsUrl: string, actionType: string, storeSelector?) {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: "SHOW_NOTIFICATION", payload: {code: 200, message: "Getting data from server..."} });

    this._http.request(BASE_URL + endpointsUrl, { body: JSON.stringify(values), method: method })
      .map(response => response.json())
      .map(payload => ({ type: actionType, payload }))
      .subscribe({
        next: action => this.store.dispatch(action),
        error: payload => this.store.dispatch({ type: 'API_ERROR', payload }),
        complete: () => this.store.dispatch({ type: "HIDE_NOTIFICATION" })
      });

    if (storeSelector)
      return this.store.select(storeSelector);
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`timeInterval()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeinterval.html) ?

Comment: @Langley Not sure how would I use it in this case. Also it seams it's not a valid operator for `Subject`...

Comment: You mentioned `Observable` not  `Subject`, `Subject` wraps an observable though so it might have it too or something similar. It helps to specify a time the observable will call its subscribers, I thought that's what you meant by "I wanted to delay initial notification so it's not shown if request ends quickly"

Comment: `@ngrx/store.select()` returns Subject, I'll update the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with:

```
this.store.select('notification')
  .debounceTime(250)
  .subscribe((message: INotification) => this.notification = message);
```

and reverted back to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` for this component. I guess it's one of the issues with `async` pipe...

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes me think about another one:

- [Angular 2 RxJS check if mouse event is still active after delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305670/angular-2-rxjs-check-if-mouse-event-is-still-active-after-delay)

I didn't test but mixing flatMap, delay and takeUntil operators could correspond to your needs.